# Duvida com angular e checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, checkbox

Tenho um form com alguns inputs e alguns checkbox, quando faço a busca no banco é retornado *Json*, e os campos inputs são preenchidos porem os checkbox nao são marcados embora eu tenha declarado o ng-model dele:

```
 <p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="t0080_pbm_testado" id="t0080_pbm_testado" icheck ng-model="checklist.t0080_pbm_testado" />
     <label for="checkbox_demo_1" class="inline-label">Teste</label>
 </p>
```

O que há de errado?

Trecho da view

```
  <div class="uk-form-row">
    class="uk-grid">
       <p>
          <input type="checkbox" name="t0080_pbm_instalado" id="t0080_pbm_instalado" icheck ng-model="checklist.t0080_pbm_instalado" />
          <label for="checkbox_demo_1" class="inline-label">Instalação</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="t0080_pbm_configurado" id="t0080_pbm_configurado" icheck ng-model="checklist.t0080_pbm_configurado" />
        <label for="checkbox_demo_1" class="inline-label">Configuração</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="t0080_pbm_testado" id="t0080_pbm_testado" icheck ng-model="checklist.t0080_pbm_testado" />
        <label for="checkbox_demo_1" class="inline-label">Teste</label>
      </p>
       <p>
         <input type="checkbox" name="t0080_pbm_treinado" id="t0080_pbm_treinado" icheck ng-model="checklist.t0080_pbm_treinado" />
         <label for="checkbox_demo_1" class="inline-label">Treinamento</label>
      </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

metodo da controller angular

```
 $scope.checklist = {};
$scope.getCheckList = function () {      
        var url = "http://localhost:23714/CheckList/getCheckList?idEmpresa=1&user=a&pass=1";

    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
        $scope.checklist = data;
    })
};
```

** os inputs são preenchidos normalmente, os checkbox nao

Comment: Poste o código que tenta marcar o checkbox por favor. Use o botão de edição.

Comment: Como vc está setando `checklist.t0080_pbm_testado`?

Comment: Ah, e como está o Json que retorna da sua API?

Comment: Thiago Lunardi, editei o post e colocquei os codigos lá, obrigado por enquanto

Answer (score 1):

No exemplo abaixo o elemento `t0080_pbm_testado` é corretamente marcado como checado via *dirty checking* do Angular após 3 segundos:

```js
function SampleController($scope, $timeout) {

  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.checklist = {t0080_pbm_testado: true}

  }, 3000);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="t0080_pbm_testado" id="t0080_pbm_testado" icheck ng-model="checklist.t0080_pbm_testado"/>
        <label for="checkbox_demo_1" class="inline-label">Teste</label>
      </p>      
      
      {{checklist | json }}
      
    </div>
  </body>
```

Seu erro pode estar acontecendo por falha na atualização do objeto `$scope.checklist`, ou porque a população deste está ocorrendo fora do ciclo de *digest* do angular.